# cURL PHP, content-type is NULL - why?

Tags: php, curl

I'm trying to get data from an API using cURL/PHP. It was working an hour ago, but the code is now broken, and I can't get it to work again! I think the error is stemming from content-type being NULL, and I can't see why. Please help!!

```
$query = curl_init();
curl_setopt($query, CURLOPT_URL,'https://api.domain.com/v1/resource?somevariable=FAKE');
curl_setopt($query, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Authorization:XXXXXXXX-API-KEY-XXXXXXXXXXX',
    'Content-Type:application/json'
));
curl_setopt($query, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
$result = curl_exec($query);
$info = curl_getinfo($query);
var_dump($info);
curl_close($query);
```

And var_dumping `$info` gives me

```
array(26) { ["url"]=> string(103) "https://api.domain.com/v1/resource?somevariable=FAKE" ["content_type"]=> NULL ["http_code"]=> int(0) ["header_size"]=> int(0) ...
```

Any thoughts?! Thank you so much!!

Comment: Has the API changed?

Comment: just as well you use git for version control then. right?

Comment: HTTP code 0 means no response, which also explains the no content type. Most likely this is an SSL problem. Try `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);` and `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);` (debugging only, not on your production env).

Comment: Is the API up ? from php official doc : `Content-Type: of the requested document. NULL indicates server did not send valid Content-Type: header`

Comment: try echoing `curl_error()`

Comment: The content-type isn't the only thing that is missing. The HTTP status code is reported as 0. And so on. You should [check for error messages](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-error.php).

Comment: Hi everyone, thanks so much for the help. You're all spot on, echoing `curl_error()` gives `Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to api.domain.com:443` - I'm running this script on localhost, but it was working this morning. I guess the API might have blocked my activity? I will try running my code on a server with SSL.

Comment: Doing a bit more digging through other parts of the API I managed to get this message: `[API service name] is currently unavailable, please try again later` - so this might be a service problem!